How to keep arrays in VS2022 Watch window expanded when restaring the programm?
Having arrays like
arr, 10

in Watch 1 window in Visual Studio 2022, I have to expand arrays to see the content since they collapse every time after program restart.
This is quite inconvenient. Is there a way to keep some (or at least all) of arrays expanded after restart?

After I did some testing, VS really didn't have such a feature that would allow the watch window to expand directly after restarting the program. If you really want to keep the array watch window expanded when you restart the program, I suggest you report this feature request to DC, where there are many VS developers who may be able to help you:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
It is important to note that if there are enough users submitting requests for this feature, Microsoft may process the feature request in this area, and if there are not many users submitting the feature request, Microsoft may not consider this aspect of the feature.

This doesn't answer the question. It would be better to just add as a Comment in future.
